# Not sure how to structure data where each sample has samples

Tags: machine-learning, python, data-transformation, dataset, scikit-learn

I am unsure how to structure my data.

My goal is to build a model that can predict if a family participates in musical theater based on the features of its members. I planned to use models from scikit-learn but I am open to building my own classifier.

The highest level is families, and an assignment of whether this family is involved with musical theater (1 or 0). Each  family has an arbitrary number of people in it, (I'm assuming the number of people doesn't matter) and each member has features that I want to train on. Each person has the same number of features as every other--but families have different numbers of people.

So, I am not sure how to train a model on a family of people, where the family has one label but each person has individual ones.

My only idea so far is to train on a vector of tuples, where each tuple is all the features for each family member. Then there would be one vector of tuples per family, and one label per family. Thoughts? Is this compatible with scikit-learn?

I would appreciate any advice on how to approach this! Thank you for reading.